# Why does deploying on Kubernetes take so long?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

After I deploy something, it takes forever to get the external IP address. I'm just continually reloading this

`kubectl get service MY-DEPLOYMENT-NAME`

And after about 7 mintues, I'll get an IP address. Why does this take so long?

Comment: Cluster-ip or external-ip? Are you running Kubernetes on a cloud provider?

Comment: External-IP; Yes, I'm running it on GCE.

Comment: Is there a way to speed it up? Say by specifying the IP specifically?

Comment: It will take time for GCE to bring up the load balancer for the service. I don't use GCE so I don't know if 7 minutes is the usual amount of time it takes to do this but it seems high.

Comment: 7 minutes is a bit high. Can you post your service yaml so we can have a more detailed look?